# software testing methodologies

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

What are the best ways to evaluate the following examples?

A couple of weeks ago, I started to read about Types of Software testing:
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/types-of-software-testing/

And I'm struggling how to apply them to the real life, my background is not a programmer, but my work requires it and I need some help with some examples for:

- What is the best way to test and ATM and how would you do it?
- How to test the sofware of the operator interface in an elevator?
- How would you apply the black box technique to the software of a smart washing machine?

Thanks for your help and guide.

Comment: Please explain how your work requires it.  Is this for an interview / take-home exercise?

Comment: Be aware that 'three in one' questions are not well suited to our Q&A and voting format.  If one answer has 2 good bits and another answer 1 excellent bit, it's hard to up-vote and see the top answer to a specific question.

Comment: Anna, this question likely will get closed. You need to ask 3 different questions (and give us some background), as suggested by @MichaelDurrant, read: [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: You need to split this question into three questions and explain why you need answers, what you have done to look for answers, and *most importantly* what you think your answers are. Without that, this just looks like you're trying to get us to do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all those questions is similar:

- What are the requirements ?
- What are the use cases ?
- What exceptions will arise ?
- What edge and boundary cases should be tested ?
- What are the environmental factors that can change ?
- What are the characteristics of the users ?
- What are the volume and performance requirements ?

As for the document you reference... we're not going to be able to answer what to do about Black box testing / White box testing / Unit testing / Incremental integration testing / Integration testing / Functional testing / System testing / End-to-end testing / Sanity testing / Regression testing / Acceptance testing / Load testing in one question, other than think about them in regard to the points I've listed.  Please separate out and ask specific questions on this site.

Comment: What is the best way to test and ATM and how would you do it?to use types of software testing

Comment: ok, however you need to ask that as a new question.  
Also - try to at least list *some* obvious things in the question.  It's an ATM and so obviously you should be able to...